why I can't catch a error with my function call in an async function?
I have the code below, as long as my function doesn't have async keyword at the beginning of it, there is no problem catching the exception at the function call but when I add async keyword to the function, I'm unable to catch the exception at the function call, I'm just wondering why it's not possible to catch the exception at the function call in an async function?
p.n: I know I can catch thee exception inside the body of the async function, I'm just wondering why it's not possible in the function call.
code:
//async function

async function lome() {
throw new Error("error");
}

try { lome() } catch { console.log("hey") };

//output: error

//normal function

function lome() {
throw new Error("error");
}

try { lome() } catch { console.log("hey") };

//output:hey 

p.n2: it's not possible to add await next to my function call, and if you mean I have to  use await inside my async function body, still it's not  helping to catch the error.
code:
async function lome() {
throw new Error("error");
}

try { await lome() } catch { console.log("hey") };


//output: Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async 
//functions and the top level bodies of modules.

async function lome() {
return await Promise.reject(99)
}

try { lome() } catch { console.log("hey") }

//output: error(I have tested with and without `return` keyword).


You must await lome() to catch async errors or get async results.

check p.n2 @deceze

"it's not possible to add await" — Well, then you can't catch errors nor get a result from the function.

Wrap the try-catch block in an async function: (async () => { try { ... } catch { ... } })()

tnx @Yousaf, but I already have the solution as I've mentioned in first p.n, more I was looking for the reason why this event is happening in this scenario and I'm unable to catch a error at function call.

The result of an async function will always be asynchronous, whether an exception or a return value. You must await it, or .then(...).catch(...) it. That's why.

Exception that is thrown asynchronously cannot be caught synchronously. You have to await the lome function call to catch the exception that is thrown asynchronously. And to await the lome function call, you need to wrap the try-catch block in an async function

it's not possible to use await outside an async function unless we're in a top-level module (and clearly currently, we're not in one of them), and yes it's possible to catch the error (read p.n1) but I'm looking for this specific behaviour and issue of being unable to catch a error at function call in an async function.@deceze

the example I've issued in this question gets executed synchronously(check your browser console for output)...@Yousaf

An async function always returns a promise. The code inside the function is synchronous but the result is asynchronous because it is an async function. You cannot treat it like a synchronous function.

I don't know what you want to hear here. There isn't any other way to explain this. If function is async, use await or .then.catch you must. You must use .then.catch or await if your function is async. Should your function happen to be async, you cannot get its result without using async or .then.catch.

@Yousaf your comment help me to get the idea, and I realized why this is acting like this, it's because promise has it's own way of error handling, .catch() . so  sometimes it has some spontaneous issues with try...catch.

await fun() is actually syntactic sugar for fun().then(...). try { await fun() } catch ... is actually syntactic sugar for fun().catch(...). You can use either way, but you must use either way with async functions/promises. It's no "issues", it's how it works.
